# How to get attribute from child node through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

Below mentioned is a node in a webpage and the objective is to get the data inside the attribute "onclick". I am aware that i can use `GetAttribute("onclick")` to get the data.

But for a reason I am only locating the td inside which this input node is present. Can someone tell if there is a way to get the attribute data "onclick" of the child 'input' node from parent 'td' node.

```
 <td align="center">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="View Pdf" onclick="showFilePreView('98374');">
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use selenium-webdriver, then you could find the parent element first, then use `childElement = parentElemnent.FindElement(By.)` to find the child.

In your case, you could try the code below:

```
IWebElement parentElement = YourWebDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("td"));
// those codes above assume that there is only one "td" node in your case.    

IWebElement childElement = parentElement.FindElement(By.Name("button"));
String theStringYouWant = childElement.GetAttribute("onclick");
```

Hope those code could solve your case.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an *dynamic* element so to get the *value* of the attribute *onclick* i.e. **showFilePreView('98374')** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be visible and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("td[align='center']>input.button[value='View Pdf']"))).GetAttribute("onclick")
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//td[@align='center']/input[@class='button' and @value='View Pdf']"))).GetAttribute("onclick");
  ```

**Note**: Here the assumption is the `<td>` node is unique within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)